# Choosing 10 staff members from a single branch probability

Tags: probability

If a company has 6 branches with the following staff counts:

- Branch A: 15 staffs
- Branch B: 10 staffs
- Branch C: 12 staffs
- Branch D: 19 staffs
- Branch E: 16 staffs
- Branch F: 6 staffs

what is the probability of choosing all 10 staffs from a single branch for retrenchment?

From A to E is calculatable, but for F, is the probability 0, since 10 is greater than 6?

Comment: It is true that $\binom nk=0$ when $k>n$...

Comment: OK thanks! @ParclyTaxel

Comment: It is clearly impossible to choose all $10$ from the $6$ staff in F, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k > n$,

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)....(2)(1)(0)(-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!} = 0$$

Not undefined, btw, since denominator is guarenteed to be greater than 0.